Adding external delta table in Kusto does not work, table too big?
I would like to add an external table to Azure Data Explorer. Format is delta.
I am using the statement
.create async external table mybigtable
kind=delta 
( 
   h@'abfss://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2;kwnZN9+IDpl4JIieNEzaBiQ+/rrjrjrjUfxonyuxginfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhhfh'
) 

This will return the following error message:

The delta table is big (row count > 1.5000.000.000.000). Is it possible to add it anyway as an external table in ADX ?

you could try setting the request timeout to a higher value (up to an hour). AFAICS, the table in your specific case should be created within 25-30 minutes, due to the current time it takes to read and validate the delta table

Set it to 25 minutes, connection works ! thanks @YoniL.

out of curiosity - how are you creating/writing to/maintaining your delta table? are you following best practices for optimizing it? (e.g., see: https://docs.delta.io/latest/best-practices.html#best-practices and https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html)

tables are created by a spark cluster with optimizations
